# Chirality and achirality terminology

Tags: geometry, terminology, symmetry

This is more terminological/linguistical question than technical.

Suppose I have a periodical structure which I would describe as
"chiral". See "chirality":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality

And a similar structure, but achiral. And say, I apply *morphing* to the chiral structure to make it achiral and vice versa.
E.g. this image demonstrate this:

[image]

**Question**

- Which terms one would apply to describe "the amount, or grade, of 
  chirality in a structure"?
- Which terms one would apply to describe the process of "increasing/decreasing this amount of chirality"?

Comment: Chirality is like being pregnant. Either you have it or you don't. There is no such thing as being partly chiral. The left image is not chiral, the right image is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair funny yes. and still I need to call it somehow in a paper. amount of twist? So I must give a characteristic how 'chiral' is a structure. IOW for some taken axes of symmetry how much information reflects in itself.

Comment: I was less making a joke, than trying to illustrate a point. Though I suppose if you can establish some sort of "distance" measure between images in the image space, you could grade chirality by how far it is to the nearest chiral image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to measure quantitatively how a structure deviates from chirality.

It is not just "chiral" or "achiral".

Theory: see the papers cited on http://petitjeanmichel.free.fr/itoweb.petitjean.html